# how to remove row from dgrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have defined dgrid and a button for removing row:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0/css/dgrid.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body class="claro">


    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="remove">Remove</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            packages: [
                { name: 'dgrid', location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0' },
                { name: 'dstore', location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dstore/v1.1.1' }
           ]
        };
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    require([
                'dojo/_base/declare',
                'dojo/on',
                "dojo/dom", 
                "dstore/Memory",
                "dstore/Trackable",
                'dstore/SimpleQuery', 
                'dgrid/Grid', 
                'dgrid/extensions/Pagination',
                'dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry',
                'dojo/domReady!'
    ],
   function(declare, on, dom, Memory, Trackable, SimpleQuery, Grid, Pagination, DijitRegistry) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
                data.push({id:i,name: 'Name '+i, value: i});
        }

        var Store = declare([Memory, SimpleQuery, Trackable]);
        var myStore = new Store({data:data});

        var MyGrid = declare([Grid, Pagination]);
        var grid = new MyGrid({
                collection: myStore,
                columns: {
                        'id' : 'Id',
                        'name' : 'Name',
                        'value' : 'Value'
                },
                className: "dgrid-autoheight",
                showLoadingMessage: false,
                noDataMessage: 'No data found.'
        }, 'container');
        grid.startup();
        on(dom.byId('remove'),'click',function() {
                myStore.remove(10);
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The dgrid shows up, you can sort it, edit name or value.

The problem is, that when you click on the "remove" button, row is deleted, but then, at the end of the gird is 9x written: "No data found" and the dgrid stops to work (you cant delete any other row).

If you set showLoadingMessage: to true, then everything works without a problem.

Edit: I have simplified the example. Problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

The grid may have been encountering error while updating the row data after the row has been removed. As the editor tries to update the row after the button loses focus. Try using the grid.removeRow method to remove the row. It might still encounter some other issues, but worth a try.

`Editor` might not be the best solution to achieve what your are trying to do.

User renderCell to add button to the grid, to remove the row/record. This might be a better solution.

Update: Just refresh the grid that should solve the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0/css/dgrid.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body class="claro">


    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="remove">Remove</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            packages: [
                { name: 'dgrid', location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0' },
                { name: 'dstore', location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dstore/v1.1.1' }
           ]
        };
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    require([
                'dojo/_base/declare',
                'dojo/on',
                "dojo/dom", 
                "dstore/Memory",
                "dstore/Trackable",
                'dstore/SimpleQuery', 
                'dgrid/Grid', 
                'dgrid/extensions/Pagination',
                'dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry',
                'dojo/domReady!'
    ],
   function(declare, on, dom, Memory, Trackable, SimpleQuery, Grid, Pagination, DijitRegistry) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
                data.push({id:i,name: 'Name '+i, value: i});
        }

        var Store = declare([Memory, SimpleQuery, Trackable]);
        var myStore = new Store({data:data});

        var MyGrid = declare([Grid, Pagination]);
        var grid = new MyGrid({
                collection: myStore,
                columns: {
                        'id' : 'Id',
                        'name' : 'Name',
                        'value' : 'Value'
                },
                className: "dgrid-autoheight",
                showLoadingMessage: false,
                noDataMessage: 'No data found.'
        }, 'container');
        grid.startup();
        on(dom.byId('remove'),'click',function() {
            myStore.remove(10);
            grid.refresh();
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I cant use this. First, If I use Editor and change value by it, the result is again meny "No data found" results. Also store should be independent on the grid, so when I use store. remove(), I shoud not know about grid. And the third problem is, that I want to use async store (instead of memory), so this solution would means that the grid will refresh before the results is returned and rendered. And It also blinks with the Editor, like If I used showLoadingMessage:true. :(

Comment: In that case you need to use OnDemandGrid instead of just Grid. dgrid/Grid is lightweight grid used to load data. It does not have functionality to update itself. you would need to refresh it if you updated the data within the store. I have tested it http://jsbin.com/neyemujeza/edit?html,output however, the showLoadingMessage must be set to true. for some reason its messed up when you set it to false. I shall investigate it later.

Comment: According to the documentation, you should not use OnDemandGird and Pagination together. With showLoadingMessage: true my example works, so I do not need OnDemandGrid anyway. But I do not want to use showLoadingMessage: true , because then every change in the store causes blinking the grid (especially if you do not use Memory but some kind of Rest store).